# How would I plot a graph from a large array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I have a numpy array `[(a1, x1), (a2, x2), ..., (a100, x100)]` and I need to plot it such that a is my y-axis and x is my x-axis.

I know that it would be easier to have `[a1, a2, ..., a100]` and `[x1, x2, ..., x100]` as separate arrays to plot, but I'm doing a project, and I've been specifically told to do it this way, but am struggling.

Attempt 1 gave me a graph, but I think it's plotted a graph of a and x values against their numbers of order in the array.

Attempt 2, which was suggested by a matplotlib website just gave me a long error message.

```
# attempt 1 
plt.plot(array,'r.') 
plt.show()
plt.close()

# attempt 2 
plt.plot(array_1[0], array_1[1:],'r.') 
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just reshape and unpack to get the quantities you want: `a, x = array.T` followed by `plt.plot(a,x)`, or unpack with the `*` operator: `plt.plot(*array.T)`. In this sequence `T` is for transpose and loosely stated `*(a,b,c,d) = a,b,c,d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array is a numpy array with shape (100,2) you can do:

```
plt.plot(arr[:,1],arr[:,0])
```

The way to read this is:

[ first dimension, second dimension ] 
where `:` is "all of the dimension" and the indices 1 and 2 specify position in the dimension.

So the code
`arr[:,1]` means "all the rows", "second element"

edit:
After discussing with OP it appears that his/her array shape is actually (202,)

You can fix this by reshape.

```
array_1 = array_1.reshape(-1,2)
plt.plot(arr[:,1],arr[:,0])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! When I do that I get the error message 'IndexError: too many indices for array'. I think my array should be 2x100, but when i print it, it comes in rows of 4... so I'm not sure if I have to format a shape for it first?

Comment: can you type arr.shape and report the result?

Comment: i just need the values of  "type(arr)" and "arr.shape"

Comment: 'array_1 = np.array([a, x])/ array_1 = np.append(array_1, [a,x])'

Comment: the slash is for a line break

Comment: still not giving me the values for array_1.shape

Comment: hi, I'm really sorry, but I'm super new to coding. I dont have any function about array shape...

Comment: all numpy arrays have a shape attribute so you can  type print(array_1.shape) at the end of your code

Comment: I would have assumed it would be 2x100, but when I hit print there are rows of 4... I'm not sure if that's just because my window can only fit four in a row or if I've set it that way...

Comment: print it out and report here.. otherwise i have to guess.

Comment: there you go, try that

Comment: (and accept post if it works :-) , i work for upvotes hehe)

Comment: so what is actually happening is that your array is a long one dimensional thing [ a1, x1, a2, x2, a3,x3 ... because of the append.

Comment: ah... thank you so much! It's now got a shape of (101, 2), and when I print the array it looks great! How do i do upvotes?

Comment: click the arrow up next to my answer, and "accept" also.

Comment: not yet, but thanks for trying :-)  Good luck with your coding journey.

Comment: (not the little one on the comments here, but the big one on top :-) )

Comment: ah... sorry! Done now x